# Change class with javascript and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add or remove classes when the user click on a th, that should change the image that is on css...

So, i have this html:

```
<th class="etiqueta_grid" onclick="client.orderMethod('Name',this.cellIndex);">Name</th>
```

and this is the javascript method:

```
sort : "ASC",
order : "Client",
orderMethod : function(field,object){
            $(client.domroot_nav + " #grid-head2 th").removeClass('down').removeClass('up');

        if(field == client.order){
            if(client.sort == "ASC"){
                client.sort = "DESC";
                $(client.domroot_nav + " #grid-head2 th:eq("+object+")").addClass('up');
            }else{
                client.sort = "ASC";
                $(client.domroot_nav + " #grid-head2 th:eq("+object+")").addClass('down');
            }
        }else{
            client.sort = "ASC";
            client.order = field;
            $(client.domroot_nav + " #grid-head2 th:eq("+object+")").addClass('down');
        }
        client.show();

        return false;
    }
```

and i put this on css:

```
.down:before{
   background-image: url(images/down.png);
    background-size: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px; 
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    content:"";  
 }
 .etiqueta_grid{
     content: "";
 }
 .up{
    background-image: url(images/up.png);
    background-size: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px; 
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    content:""; 
 }
```

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you elaborate more than "it doesn't work"

Comment: I'm sorry, the sorting works, so it detects when clicking, but doesn't change the image that is an up or down arrow, it's the one that must change when clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery toggleClass for this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function){
        $("th").click(function(){
            $("#elementid").toggleClass("up");
        });
    });
</script>
```